# wp_loaded with static Singleton

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

In my WordPress site, I created a `Singleton` inside a custom plugin I have, like this:

```
class VBWpdb {
    private $trace = array();

    public static function get_instance() {
        static $instance = null;
        if(null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    //...
```

So, I'm using `VBWpdb::get_instance()` in a lot of places of my code to populate `$trace` array (first var of the class). It works for the purpose of having a trace along my code and this static class is being the only instance during the plugin execution. I tested with arbitrary `var_dump`'s...

The problem is... I want to print that trace once my page is loaded and I'm doing this:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'vb_dump_wpdb_trace');
function vb_dump_wpdb_trace() {
    VBWpdb::get_instance()->dump();
}
```

It seems that this instance is not being created again, but `$trace` is `NULL`.

Am I missing something related to object living span on WordPress layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just doing it wrong. The problem starts with using a singleton, just never do it.

You have a class of loggers which logs into some internal buffer. All loggers log into the same buffer, therefor the buffer (`trace` in your case) a static array in the class.
No more `get_intance`, just instantiate a new logger and log. This gives you the added flexibility of having several classes of loggers that "output" to the same buffer.

We are left with a question of how to inspect the log, and this you do with a static method.

I am sure this scheme can be improved by people that are more hard core OOP than me, using singleton is equivalent to using a `namespace` and code written under a namespace is easier to read and use than the singleton, just call a function directly with no need to handle the complications of getting an object first, it is easier to use a function in a hook, etc.

Comment: your statement that singletons should never be used, in my opinion, is a bit to strong. There are tons of articles discussing pros and cons of using them, but all depends how, and in what situation we use them.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz, singleton is at best a weak OOP pattern that keep being used in wordpress plugin and theme development and generates real world problems especially in the case where a `get_instance` type of function is not being made available. If you will show me even one singleton used in wordpress that would not have been better written with namespaces I promise to upvote all your answers ;)

Comment: ... as for the general debate, maybe it is interesting in pure OOP languages, but PHP is hybrid and no one forces you to write classes. Classes should be used to define the properties and behaviors of several objects, and if you know you are going to have only one, it does not make any sense to add the overhead of classes for no gain.

Comment: we don't know if his plugin uses just one class or more, and if they are necessary. Sure, PHP has no complete OOP design, but just extensibility and inheritance ( when used ) are good enough reasons to use them, as core does.

Comment: it is not "one class" it is the "one object that can be instantiated for that class" which is the problem. As for inheritance.... at least one respected member around here will tell you that if you have no abstract interface classes you are not doing OOP..... lets be real, no one ever inherits or does anything remotely OOP with the singletons classes in plugins and themes

Answer (score 0):

Your function `get_instance` will never create an instance of the class because of this line:

```
$instance = new static();
```

it should be:

```
$instance = new VBWpdb();
```